# Linear programming constraints: multiplication of optimization variables

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, linear-programming

Given an optimization problem with two optimization variables (`x_in(t)`, `x_out(t)`). For any time-step, when `x_in` is non-zero, `x_out` must be zero (and vice versa). Written as a constraint:

```
x_in(t)*x_out(t)=0
```

How can such a constraint be included in Matlab's `linprog` function?

Comment: `linprog` stands for **LINEAR** programing. This constraint is NOT linear (it's quadratic)...

Answer (score 5):

Since the problem is not entirely linear, I do not believe you can solve it as-is using the `linprog` function. However, you should be able to reformulate the problem as a [mixed integer linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem. Then you would be able to use for example [this extension](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25259) from *Matlab Central* to solve the problem.

Assuming that `x_in(t)` and `x_out(t)` are non-negative variables with upper bounds `x_in_max` and `x_out_max`, respectively, then you can add the variables `y_in(t)` and `y_out(t)` to your optimization problem and include the following constraints:

```
(1) y_in(t) and y_out(t) are binary, i.e. 0 or 1
(2) x_in(t)  <= x_in_max  * y_in(t)
(3) x_out(t) <= x_out_max * y_out(t)
(4) y_in(t) + y_out(t) = 1
```

Given that `y_in` and `y_out` are binary variables, constraints (2) and (3) relate the `x_` and `y_` variables with each other and ensure that the `x_` variables remain within bounds (fix bounds on the `x_` variables can thus and *should be* removed from the problem formulation). Constraint (4) ensures that either the `_in` or the `_out` event occurs, but not both at the same time.

Comment: I believe (4) should be `y_in(t) + y_out(t) <= 1`, to be equivalent to the OP formulation (both `y_in(t)` and `y_out(t)` can be equal to `0` at the same time)

Comment: Thanks, @NicolasGrebille. This is not the way I interpret the problem formulation above, but if it is indeed a possibility that `x_in(t)` and `x_out(t)` are zero at the same time, just change constraint (4) to the inequality formulation.